# SQLite delete is slow

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, sql-delete, sqlperformance

I have 10000 records in a table in my SQLite db. When I try to delete some of it's records I get that the result that it has deleted the records in milliseconds which nearly about 500ms. But in reality the background process continues for nearly 8 seconds. I tried using transaction, cache size,  but I do not get it to work to get a better performance. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the code in question?

Comment: May be this can help : [sqlite delete slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707190/sqlite-delete-incredibly-slow-how-to-speed-up)

Comment: Background process? Sqlite does everything in the process executing the query, not a server like most databases.